# git push will only work under `sudo`

Tags: git, ssl, openssl

When I try to `push` a git repository to `github`:

```
julia_proj git:(master) git push -u origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nickleeh/julia_proj.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I tried to use `sudo`:

```
julia_proj git:(master) sudo git push -u origin master
[sudo] password for nick: 
Username for 'https://github.com': nickleeh
Password for 'https://nickleeh@github.com': 
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 373 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/nickleeh/julia_proj.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

I'm so surprised that it works under `sudo`, (it also require me to input github account name and password.) What's wrong here and how can I set up this without using `sudo`?

Software environment:

```
➜  julia_proj git:(master) uname -a
Linux nick-thinkpad 4.2.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 27 08:13:28 CET 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
➜  julia_proj git:(master) git --version
git version 2.6.4
➜  julia_proj git:(master)
```

Comment: Is `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` readable by everybody? Should be owned by root but perms `-rw-r--r--`

Comment: @engineerC Thanks, I've got `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 Sep  4 15:22 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -> ../../ca-certificates/extracted/tls-ca-bundle.pem` for `ls -l`.

Comment: It's a symlink, you have to check perms on what it's pointing to (`ls -lL`).

Comment: @engineerC `ls -lL`: `-r--r--r-- 1 root root 253759 Nov  7 01:53 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` It seems no problem here?

Comment: Double check what ca-cert both root and your user are trying to use (`curl -sv https://github.com/ 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'CAfile'`), and that you can actually read the specified file (both the symlink and target if it's linked) with your user (`file` is a good command to verify with).

Comment: Also, maybe a `sudo chwon -R nick /home/nick` may be helpful, especially if you did something with sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have determined which certificates file (as mentioned by [Guildencrantz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91449/guildencrantz)) you are using:

```
 curl -sv https://github.com/ 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'CAfile'
```

do (without sudo)

```
cd /path/to/your/local/repo
git config http.sslCAInfo /path/to/certificates
```

If the push works, set that for all repos:

```
cd /any/path/you/want
git config --global http.sslCAInfo /path/to/certificates
```

Comment: I did exactly what specified in your answer; however, the push failed. I tried `git remote remove origin` and `git remote add origin git@github.com:nickleeh/julia_proj.git`, it works this time. I don't know whether this problem is caused by the misuse of `https` and `SSH: git@...`. Thank you for your detailed steps.

Comment: @Nick http sslCAInfo is only for https url. If you remove the origin and replace it with an ssh url, then your all question becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @Nick when you said that the push failed, did it failed with the original https url? And if yes, with which error message? The same one?

Comment: Yes, it failed with the orginal `https://nickleeh@github.com` and the error message is the same: `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nickleeh/julia_proj.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Comment: @Nick then the path you mentioned in http.sslCAInfo is not accessible from the regular user. Can you do a cat of that file?

Comment: Yes, I did a `cat /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`, the output is too long to paste here. `head /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` is : `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDzzCCAregAwIBAgIDAWweMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQ........`

Comment: Does  a sudo curl command return the same as the curl you did to get that file?

Comment: Also, CA you compare sudo git config --global with git config --global? Maybe there is one other setting which might explain that error message.

Comment: Yes, `sudo curl ...` return the same file.